# how to partition an array into s number of sub arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to divide an array into s number of subarrays using NumPy. I randomly generated an array x ranging from 0 to 1 and I want to divide that array into equally spaced intervals. So if I want 5 intervals, they would be the intervals 0 to 0.2, 0.2 to 0.4, 0.4 to 0.6, 0.6 to 0.8, and 0.8 to 1.0 and I want to sort these my array into these divisions.

```
x=np.array(np.random.uniform(0,1,100))

def partition_array(array,S):
    a = np.linspace(0,1,S+1)
    b = np.partition(array,0)
    print(a)
    print(b)

partition_array(x,5)
```

a creates my intervals with the selected number and b just orders my array. I tried to use the zip function and make a loop to read off of a and b, but was unable to come to a solution. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you want `np.partition`.  That's a partial sorting.

Comment: I will eventually have to create a histogram, but 'm not sure. I'm supposed to produce outputs that look like The number of entries in the subintervals are [15, 18, 19, 26, 22]
The subinterval mid points of the intervals are [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]

Comment: You might also look at `np.digitize`.

Comment: I was able to make a function using np.histogram.                                              
def partition_array(array,S):
    np.sort(array)
    a = np.array(np.histogram(array,S)[0])
    print("The number of entries in the subintervals are",a)
    
partition_array(x,5)                                                                                                      However, I am unsure how to access the data of the bins and find the subinterval midpoints. Can you reccommend anything?

Answer (score 1):

If it isn`t essential that you get an array as output you could use lists.

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array(np.random.uniform(0,1,100))
#print("Array: ") <-- debug
#print(x)
y = x.tolist()
#print("List: ")  <-- debug
#print(y)

def divide_chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

x = list(divide_chunks(y, 3))
print("Divided list: ")
print(x)
```

Note that N in this case is the size of the sublists you get as output.